# The probability of Being Late

Tags: probability

I encountered an question to the solution to a question in my probability textbook (Problem 4.23. Introduction to Probability 2nd edition, by Dimitri P. Bertsekas and John N. Tsitsiklis)

The question is copied as follows:

Pat and Nat are dating, and all of their dates are scheduled to start at 9PM. Nat always arrives promptly at 9PM. Pat is highly disorganized and arrives at a time that is uniformly distributed between 8PM and 10PM. Let X be the time in hours between 8PM and the time when Pat arrives. If Pat arrives before 9PM., their date will last exactly 3 hours. If Pat arrives after 9PM., their date will last for a time that is uniformly distributed between 0 and 3-X hours. The date starts at the time they meet. Nat gets irritated when Pat is late and will end the relationship after second date on which Pat is late by more than 45 minutes. All dates are independent of any other dates.

The question now is asking the expected number of dates they will have before breaking up.

The solution starts with finding the probability of Pat being late by more than 45 minutes and this probability is 1/8. I re-read this question a few times and it seems to me the probability is 45 minutes/2hours but obviously it is wrong. Where is the 8 (the total number of outcomes) is coming from?

Answer (score 3):

They break up if Pat arrives in the interval $9:45-10:00$, which is $15$ minutes out of $2$ hours.  That is where the chance they break up is $\frac 18$ per date comes from.  We then have a geometric distribution of the number of dates with probability $\frac 18$ of stopping each time.  The expected number before you stop is the inverse of this, or $8$.

Comment: I see. Thank  you.